# Can't take screenshots on Nexus 4

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-4

I have a rooted Nexus 4 (totally stock, except for CWM recovery). Yesterday I updated it to the 4.2.2 OTA. Today I discovered that I can't take a screenshot. Holding power + volume down should work, but when I try it the volume gets turned down or the pop-up for power off/airplane mode appears.

Is the timing for taking a screenshot really finicky? Is this a known issue in 4.2.2? (I've had the phone for less than two weeks, so I'm not sure if I tried to take a screenshot in 4.2.1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, the timing is just that finicky. Both buttons need to be pressed & held at exactly the same time to take a screenshot. I was used to a mod on my previous phone that had more relaxed timings so you could hold power and then hit volume down to take a screenshot.

Comment: Use one hand and you cannot fail to get a screenshot. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have Nexus 4 with OTA 4.2.2; screenshot works when pressing and holding for 3 seconds the <kbd>power</kbd> and <kbd>volume down</kbd> button together.